# Where is the GitHub link in the Data Exchange Explorer located?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, data-dump

I went closely over the [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com)'s [fields](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede/2678#2678), but couldn't find where the GitHub link is saved for a user:
[image]

[image]

I ran this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1716797) on my [own](https://stackoverflow.com/users/766570/abbood) profile but couldn't find my GitHub account.